# Ticket to ride, 1910: What are the big cities

Tags: ticket-to-ride

Earlier today I bought the 1910 expansion in the mobile version of Ticket to Ride. In the big cities variant, there's an achievement called "Urban Traveller", described by "Win while connecting all 7 Big Cities", but I haven't found an easily accessible list of what those are, so that's my question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From the [rules pdf](https://cdn.daysofwonder.com/tickettoride/en/img/ta_1910_rules.pdf) (also quoted in this [blog post](http://michiedo.blogspot.com/2007/12/ticket-to-ride-1910-expansion-big.html)) :

> The Big Cities are Chicago, Dallas, Houston, Los Angeles, Miami, New York and Seattle.